# How to OrderBy Hotel according to room price in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am facing a problem in my project. I have two table Hotel, Hotel Room. I want to orderBy Hotel according to get data from Hotel Room. For example

In My Hotel Table there is two hotel Hotel A, Hotel B and Hotel A has 3 Room Which price is 300, 400, 500 and Hotel Hotel B has price 600, 700, 800. I want To show the hotel according to the price in ascending order of Price.

here is my code

```
if($request->fprice) {
    $fprice = $request->fprice;
} else {
    $fprice = 'asc';
}

$hotels = Hotel::active()->with('ratings')
    ->with(['rooms' => function ($query) use ($room_type, $checkin, $checkout, $fprice) {
        if ($room_type) {
            $query->where('room_type_id', $room_type->id);
        }

        $query->orderBy('default_price', $fprice);

}])->paginate($this->perpage);
```

Thanks In advance

Comment: Without seeing your code it's difficult to see your implementation. Do you have a relationship between Hotel and Hotel Room? You could try query the Hotel Room model with Hotel relation & order the result by price...but showing some code helps us to help you

Comment: @JIJOMONK.A I had added my code. plz take  a look

Comment: @EdenWebStudio I had added my code. plz take a look

Comment: You have 2 hotels and 6 rooms. How would You show it? Like Hotel A first then Hotel B?

Comment: Agree with the other comments, the implementation is unclear. Can you post your table schemas please?

Answer (score 0):

In this case  you probably want to use `whereHas()`, something like this:

```
$hotel = Hotel::whereHas('HotelRoom', function($query) {
        $query->orderBy('price', 'DESC');
    })->get();
```

plus whatever other conditions you have in your query.

For reference: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations